# How to sell paid application from an unsupported country

Tags: android, google-play

I want to sell an application developed by me, but this service is not supported in my country (Romania).
So I want to ask a friend of mine who lives in a country (France or US) where selling paid applications is possible to help me with this.
Now I don't know exactly what to tell him about the process:
What is required by his side ? A bank account or a credit card ? How the money are transferred to him ? What exactly Google checks to verify if the developer is in one of the supported countries ?
Please help me to understand the process as I'm new in the Android world :)

Comment: *Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the faq*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: how to distribute paid application when paid Google Play is not available in my country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309811/android-how-to-distribute-paid-application-when-paid-google-play-is-not-availab)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. You can use paypal. I don't know how
   it's done but there a few apps with
   paypal.
2. You can check http://hyperbees.com/

I went through the same thing as you and decided to work with hyperbees.

Comment: Hi, i am at the same position now and since hyperbees isn't anymore publishing apps  do you know any other service like that?

Comment: @SteveL: Nope, sorry. Now my country supports selling apps.