# How to add non-free application in Android market from unsupported country (Latvia)?

Tags: android, google-play

How to add non-free application in Android market from unsupported country (Latvia)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932829/how-to-sell-paid-application-from-an-unsupported-country

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can provide your app to someone who you 'trust' in a country where Google allows developers to sell their apps. This person can act on your behalf and then transfer the earnings back to you after the tax-deductions.

But I am not sure about the legal rules that would govern this.