# Paid app to play store from unsupported area

Tags: android, google-play

I have developed an Android Application which I'd like to sell on Google Play, but unfortunately I'm from Hungary and can't upload paid apps. I'm basically looking for solutions to do this. I have already uploaded free apps. Do you know any companies who would put my application on play store? Or if there is another way, what is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sell paid application from an unsupported country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932829/how-to-sell-paid-application-from-an-unsupported-country)

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by registering a legal corporation (an LLC) in USA, and then selling my apps through that.

I paid [LegalZoom](http://legalzoom.com/) to set it up for me.

Keep in mind that you will have to file taxes etc. in USA, as well as have a bank account there in your company's name to be able to receive payments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm afraid I can't pay for that :(