# Android: how to distribute paid application if paid market is STILL not available in my country

Tags: android, google-play

How to distribute paid application if paid market is STILL not available in my country?

I don't want to involve third parties like androidpublisher. Amazon app store is not sufficient option. I live in Poland.

Answer (score 2):

Even though Google doesn't like it, you can distribute your app as a free ("LITE") app on the market, and add an unlock mechanism that either validates through your server, or by entering a serial number

You will need to manually send the license number (or file) after getting paid with PayPal or a similar service

A similar concept was made by Launcher Pro and Titanium Backup, before they could publish a paid app on the market

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309811/android-how-distribute-paid-application-when-paid-market-is-not-available-in-my/2311208#2311208 as said here i can't do that :(

Comment: That is the only option though :(

Answer (score 0):

Effective from 2012-04-12, developers from Poland can now sell apps through Mark^H Google Play.